# Merge two independent Git repositories

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-branch

I have project in two different Git repositories, one on github.com second - on local server. So on two repositories I have same projects, I need to develop project on local one and then merge to github repo. So I wrote win.bat with code

```
cd path/to/project-b
git remote add project-a path/to/project-a
git fetch project-a
git merge project-a/master # or whichever branch you want to merge
```

It's not working, because I don't want to create some sort of brunch or do 'rm origin' in any project. 
Also i tried to

```
cd  ../proj1
git pull origin
cd ../proj2
git pull ../proj1 master
git commit -a
git push origin master

cd  ../proj3/test.git
git fetch -p origin
git push --mirror

cd ../../proj1
git pull origin

ECHO Done...
```

Can you help me to create some stack of commands to marge changes from project one to project 2 ? Or say what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: “It's not working, because I don't want to create some sort of brunch or do 'rm origin' in any project.” – Can you explain what you mean with this? What’s not working? What do you expect as the outcome? (Also, what’s wrong with brunch?!)

Answer (score 0):

So this is solution to merge two repos

```
:: Bat merger two Git repositories into one.

::Original project to which we will merge
cd  proj1
git pull origin

::local project from which we will merge to original
cd ../proj2
git pull ../proj1 master
git commit -a
git push origin master


::downloading and merging local project commit hoistory 
cd  ../proj2.git
git fetch -p origin
git push --mirror

cd ../proj1
git pull origin

ECHO Done...
PAUSE
```